# How to publish the 'one' side of a one-to-many relationship in meteor after the 'many' side has been selected?

Tags: meteor, one-to-many, publish

I have two collections of objects in Meteor which are linked with a one-to-many relationship. Courses contains the _id of Places.

I have a publication that is :

```
Meteor.publish('courses', function(day_selector, price_min, price_max){
    return Courses.find({   
        day_of_week : {$in: day_selector}, 
        price : {$gt : price_min, $lt : price_max}});
});
```

I would like to create another publication that returns only the Places for which at least one course is selected.

I have read the advanced publication chapter on the discover meteor book and it seems that it is possible to send Places along with Courses but I don't understand how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while to figure this one out a few months ago but here is the solution :

```
Meteor.publish('courses',function(day_selector, price_min, price_max){
    var coursesCursor=Courses.find({
        day_of_week : {$in: day_selector}, 
        price : {$gt : price_min, $lt : price_max}
    });
    var courses=coursesCursor.fetch();
    var coursesPlacesIds=_.pluck(courses,"place_id");
    var placesCursor=Places.find({
        _id : {$in : coursesPlacesIds}
    });
    //
    return [
        coursesCursor,
        placesCursor
    ];
});
```

The key is that you can return more than one cursor from a publish function, knowing this subtle feature allows you to write publication code that publishes both of your collections documents.

The tricky part is to extract the ids of the places from the courses cursor which has been filtered by publish parameters : that's why we use underscore.pluck (see the docs).
Once we get these ids, it's very simple to return the places with another cursor.

Comment: This may be sufficient if the join doesn't need to be reactive. If you need the data to update if the relationships change you need to use an observe or a library like [pwr](https://github.com/erundook/meteor-publish-with-relations).

Comment: Actually I don't need to update for relationships changes as they won't change. Thanks a lot for your code, at the beginning I was quite confused about how Publish-Suscribe and cursor worked but after playing with it a little bit I think I have a good grasp of how it actually works.

Comment: Here's a video on publishing many-to-many relationships if it's helpful for anyone else: https://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-how-to-publish-a-many-to-many-relationship.